# Run-time Error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a downloaded CSV file that I am trying to open and then save as an .xlsx file using code.  I am very very new to VB, and have just modified code that I have found to make things work.  Yesterday the code worked great, but today it stalls out on the "wb.SaveAs" line.  The odd thing about the error is that the file actually saved to the folder.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Public Function Upload_New_Orders_Excel()

'the path to the excel workbook

Dim XcelFile As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim strExcelPath As String

Set XcelFile = New Excel.Application

Set wb = XcelFile.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mpdav\downloads\orders_export_1.csv")

wb.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\mpdav\OneDrive\Documents\R&M Hospitality\At Your Door\Daily Reports\orders_export_1.xlsx", FileFormat:=51

wb.Close

Set XcelFile = Nothing

Kill "C:\Users\mpdav\downloads\orders_export_1.csv"

strExcelPath = "C:\Users\mpdav\OneDrive\Documents\R&M Hospitality\At Your Door\Daily Reports\orders_export_1.xlsx"

'import data from excel

Call DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "temp_tbl_orders_export", "C:\Users\mpdav\OneDrive\Documents\R&M Hospitality\At Your Door\Daily Reports\orders_export_1.xlsx", True, "A1:BP1000")

Kill "C:\Users\mpdav\OneDrive\Documents\R&M Hospitality\At Your Door\Daily Reports\orders_export_1.xlsx"

End Function
```

Comment: Using `FileFormat:=51` isn't necessary if you have already specified the extension in the filename

Comment: Darrell, I tried removing this but it continues to give me the same error.  Thank you very much for taking a look at it.  Do you have any other suggestions?